# Verb meaning "to robust"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, software

I am looking for a verb meaning "to make something more robust", especially in a software engineering context.

Is "to robust" correct and understandable? "Robustify" seems to be another candidate but does not seem so common.

Comment: *Robust* is not an "official" verb. The problem with the adjective in general is that it is not necessarily clear what you mean, and so no clear synonym comes to mind. What exactly is "more robust software"? I hear this used all the time and it can mean software that has more features, fewer bugs, better ability to handle problems that arise — always more of *something* desirable, but the something is always part of a larger context and not inherent in that single word.

Comment: You might want to provide more information on the context. You could perhaps add an example sentence where you'd like to use this word.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bulletproof) at least recognizes *bulletproof* can be a verb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither robustify nor 'to robust' are correct.

You can use 'to make robust'  or any of the options Bob noted.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the phrase "make the code more robust" - in quotes - returns almost 900,000 Google hits.  Just my opinion, but I believe "to make robust" is superior to any of Bob's suggestions (I'm not trying to discredit Bob's valiant effort; I simply think that "to make more robust" is the best way of saying this).

Answer (score 14):

I would use "strengthen", "fortify", or "harden", although "harden" has a distinct security meaning.

Comment: Possibly also *to [ruggedize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruggedize)* - although this applies preferably to hardware rather than to software.

Answer (score 9):

**bolster**: *v.* Support or strengthen; prop up: "the fall in interest rates is starting to bolster confidence".

For example, "You will help refactor the code and *bolster* the test suite."

Answer (score 4):

There's no single word to describe making software more robust. Some ways of making software more robust are: simplify, debug, re-factor (especially functional decomposition and code re-use), make the interface more user friendly, make the program resilient to input errors and even recover from some runtime errors, etc.

Answer (score 4):

"Harden" comes to mind, as in hardening a computer system.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardening_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

- The closest to "*make robust*" that I can come up with is:

**revitalize**

> vt
>
> : [to give new life or vigor to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revitalize?show=0&t=1345470417)

- The second word that comes to mind is:

**enhance**

> vt
>
> : [heighten, increase; especially :  to increase or improve in value,
>   quality, desirability, or attractiveness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enhance)

Comment: I don't like *revitalize* as applied to code - nothing says the old code was "moribund." *Enhance* is the more acceptable of the two, at least in my mind, but there are too many ways to enhance software to always associate *enhancing* with *robustness*.

Comment: I agree @J.R. In the first place, I doubted if "robustness" would stick to software. I went with the more general context

Answer (score 1):

[**Stabilize**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stabilization): to make (more) stable. *He put a wedge of paper under the table to stabilize it.*

I used this today when referring to a computer program. I also needed a noun equivalent and considered both *stabilization* and [*resilience*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/resilience).

Comment: Hey, who says I'm a stabilizing force? ^_^

Comment: Welcome to ELU! This question is pretty old, and has an accepted answer, and is generally regarded as 'solved'.  There's lots of other mor recent questions [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) :)

Answer (score 0):

Robustification (n.)-- the process by which, or the act of, making a procedure or algorithm (esp. in engineering, software or statistics) less susceptible to uncertainty.

See also robustify (v.)

Answer (score -1):

"Enhence Robustness" might be what you want.
I saw it in the title of a nature article("Enhancing robustness of interdependent network under recovery based on a two-layer-protection strategy").

Comment: Hello Marquez. Welcome to English Stack Exchange. We here require our answers to be authoritative, accurate and well-cited, and your post is severely lacking in every one of these qualities. Please provide a link to the article that you have mentioned, and expand further on how you came to the conclusion.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes I use *to mature* when I need a verb, such as in process descriptions.